# SQL Merge Statement to Mapping Diagram

Tags: sql, diagram

The SQL Merge Statement is in our case used extensively to sync data from system A to system B and system B to system A.

This is often complexer. I'm looking for software that can turn those merge statements into mapping diagrams, having the "sources" on the left and the "targets" on the right with in the middle the transformations that take place. Is there such a thing?

Comment: If there were such a thing, on what OS should it run, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid candidates?

Comment: ANY OS and spending is out my scope :)

Comment: "spending is out my scope" meaning it must come without a price tag (i.e. [tag:gratis], no pay)?